# Confused about what makes air follow a wing

Tags: drag, viscosity, lift

I already asked the same question and got great answers but im also confused.

One of the answers said that I can imagine that, because air over the wing has a higher pressure than the air right above the wing it gets pushed down which is why the air follows the wing instead of just going in a straight line.

But as far as I understood another answer said that viscosity makes air stick to the surface of the wing which makes it follow the wings shape.

So what is correct?

Comment: Great question btw. Glad you asked again

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly but haven’t you ever been surprised that air can respond fast enough to fill the backside of a fast-moving wing when momentum isn’t pushing any there? I mean, I answered, but anyone who hasn’t been surprised and briefly confused by that isnt a very deep thinker imo. Is great question esp this kind of site. Also, ten percent is too high to be called an anomaly 

Comment: @AlBrown You're right that my reference to "pressure" was to simplistic, but I didn't mean that the question's answer is obvious. I only meant that the question might need to be clarified. One interpretation of the question could be, why does air remain in contact with the upper surface of the wing? A second interpretation could be, what makes the air flow smoothly over the upper surface of the wing, instead of only being turbulent? Viscosity doesn't matter for the first interpretation of the question, but it might matter for the second interpretation.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly yeah makes sense i see

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate. If you have questions about those previous answers, they should have been addressed there, and you shouldn't have accepted one of them. I wrote one of the answers, and could have edited it to clarify, but I'm not about to write another answer here.

Comment: @ Al Brown "...haven’t you ever been surprised that air can respond fast enough to fill the backside of a fast-moving wing when momentum isn’t pushing any there?" This doesn't make any sense. The wing is moving through the air (or equivalently, the air is flowing over the wing). There is no problem for the air to get to the back of the wing!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a fluid follow the wing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/658911/why-does-a-fluid-follow-the-wing)

Comment: @D.Hasley That just shows you don’t understand the process of diffusion, pressure driven flows, and how gas molecules actually travel into low pressure areas, because one cannot arrive at this full understanding by never wondering why momentum initially doesn’t seem to matter. The reason for the surprise prior to understanding this is Newton’s first law, and the ultimate explanation is that gas molecules have significant velocity in all directions, not just the direction of bulk velocity of the gas. If they did not, momentum would be meaningful and there would be delays in this “backfilling”

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly Viscosity is directly responsible for creating the layer of sheared flow at the surface (the boundary layer), which contains the vorticity which is responsible for perturbing the velocities & pressures to allow the flow to conform to the surface.

Answer (score 1):

### Summary of Summary

It’s pressure equalization that determines the final amount of gas in the space, but it’s the high particle energy/speed and small size that can make it happen fast enough to fill the backside of a wing even though momentum doesn’t seem to be pushing any air in that direction. Viscosity does not make things stick together. No-slip means surface and gas velocities are equal.

### Summary

The best way to think of a gas is an enormously large number of molecules filling every portion of space, even in a very tiny space, with high particle speeds in every direction, responding almost instantly and able to achieve equilibrium pressures and densities immediately. Anything happening macroscopically is minor comparatively and is merely an average of what the particles are doing.

Also, despite what you may have heard the ubiquitous “no-slip” boundary condition, there are not *more* molecules concentrated right on the wing than there are just off of it. There is nothing attracting the molecules to the surface. The only point of no-slip is that, at the surface, we can assume the average velocity of the gas matches that of the surface.

### Intro and model

The motion of a jet of air is just the average *net* velocity of the particles.

The particles are full of energy: Temperature is actually the kinetic energy of the molecules. For example, in an ideal gas model, the relationship between pressure and temperature is determined by modeling it as many tiny particles. Pressure comes from the particles colliding with a wall at the point we are determining pressure, in a perfectly elastic collision, transferring an impulse to the wall. Many particles do that in a given time $t$: $F= \sum \tfrac{m \cdot \Delta v_{rms} }{t}$. And this aspect of the model (particularly velocity) matches perfectly with the temperature model of the same particles: a temperature model where internal energy in the gas comes from its kinetic energy $\sum \tfrac{1}{2}mv_{rms}^2$, where $m$ is the mass of a single molecule.

### How Fast are the molecules moving

And a good guesstimate is $$v_{rms} = \sqrt { \tfrac{3RT}{M_m}} \approx \sqrt { \tfrac{3 \cdot 10 \cdot 300}{0.03}} \approx 500 m/s$$

We would have to be **around mach*-1.5* for the air’s net velocity to match the *average* particle speed of room air**. But this needs to be considered in conjunction with *how many* particles we’re talking about as pressure waves up to the speed of sound can briefly increase the local average. Also remember that this does not yet include pressure-driven net flows, which can be a significant addition at near-sonic speeds.

### How Many molecules are there

One thing to realize about a gas is the number of molecules. Avogadro’s number is huge (23$^{rd}$ order).

For example, as air is 0.0013 $g/cc$ at room pressure and temperature, and 30 $g/mol$, then even assuming a low pressure of 0.1 $atm$, which reduces density ten-fold, we have...

**In a billionth of a cubic centimeter there will be 800 trillion molecules**, each one moving on its own,
with the average speed as given. So if a space opens up, the time to fill it is minuscule and not based on net, pressure-driven flows that only determine final equilibrium of average speeds (as $p$ and $T$).

Comment: Unless you're dealing with hypersonic Mach numbers, the flow over a wing is much better described by continuum mechanics. Isaac Newton's molecular explanations failed to explain subsonic flows, and are not currently considered mainstream theories.

Comment: Is not a formal analysis. Is an estimate to show the molecules are numerous even in a tiny space, and are moving fast. Only the latter is relevant to your comment, and even there it’s just getting order of magnitude right - hence the words “and a good guesstimate is” |||| “And a good guesstimate is $v_{rms} = \sqrt { \tfrac{3RT}{M_m}} \approx \sqrt { \tfrac{3 \cdot 10 \cdot 300}{0.03}} \approx 500 m/s$.” Is that the estimate you’re referring to?

Comment: I didn't refer to any estimate. If molecules are so numerous, why are you reluctant to consider the flow to be a continuum?

Comment: The question is about air following the surface of a wing, presumably for subsonic flows where the speed of sound can be considered large enough for perturbations to spread quickly throughout the flow. vrms is essentially irrelevant, since other fluids than air could have essentially the same flowfield.